# How do I bring back my files?

Tags: unity, launcher

I just opened up ubuntu 12.04, and my toolbar was gone, as well as the launcher.  I fixed this by resetting unity, but now all applications I had previously are gone, including the terminal. Anything I do manage to open doesn't have an icon on the launcher, but if you scroll over where it's supposed to be, you get the tool tip (as in, they're invisible). Also, the icons for files are messed up, and only show the same white page for everything, and the tool bar is transparant.  Another thing is that I can't access my flash drive, even though it's plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

- Try **Ctrl+Alt+F6** to get terminal
- Reset unity
- Then **Ctrl+Alt+F7** to get back